# Do I Need Quotation Marks in my CSV File for R?

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

I am doing a project where I am using a big database of species to create a functional morphospace. I am new to R. I converted my excel files into CSV files, but some have double quotation marks around each value ("3","4","5,"), whilst others don't (3,4,5). Will this pose a problem for R, or are the quotation marks a non-issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You can usually easily coerce the types as required - if they import as character strings `("3", "4", "5")` - you can change the using functions like `as.numeric()`.  If you prefer, look at the documentation for `read.csv()` (or the tidy equivalent `read_csv()`) - you can specify data types for each column when reading them in.

Comment: Quotation marks are useful when the delimiter is within values, for example compare `id,1,2,3` vs `"id","1,2,3"`, 1st one would give us 4 columns and 2nd only 2 columns.

Comment: Can you give some example data? One way would be to use `df <- read.csv("yourfile.csv")` to read in the .csv file, then use `dput(head(df))` to get the top few rows as a copy-and-pasteable code snippet that can be added to your original question as an edit.